# azure appservice not using correct version of NPM when using child process

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-webapps

I am trying to use child process in my dot net core application to run some npm and ng commands.
I have set WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION =12.18.0 and WEBSITE_NPM_DEFAULT_VERSION=6.14.4 and in kudu powershell/cmd its showing correct version

D:\home>npm --version
6.14.4

D:\home>node -v
v12.18.0

My code in c# to run npm commands :

```
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
        processInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.Arguments = $"/C npm -version";
       
        Process process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

shows npm version as as 1.1.37 but it will display node version correclty if i use node -v as command.

Deploying from VS to AZURE

[image]

I hope some one has solution for my problem. Thank you

Comment: I could not reproduce this when I set `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`. If I do not set, then only node version is different (lowest). Are you setting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION correctly in Application Settings of the app service? https://ibb.co/nDJchmw

Comment: yes , In AppService under configuration tab and Application settings , I am setting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = 12.18.0

Comment: @krishg have you checked through command (npm -v) in kudu console or programmatically by invoking child process

Comment: By invoking child process from C# code

Comment: I have created c# -dot net core web api and invoking child process and hosting in to azure appservice and then calling that api through postman but not working for me. Dont know where i am going wrong. If possible can you share your code snippet @Krishg. I tried setting WEBSITE_NPM_VERSION =6.14.4 along with NODE version also, but no use

Comment: To be more specific, I am creating Azure appservice (windows) , are you doing with the same @krishg

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows. Did this by noticing D:\ in your question :)

Comment: @krishg Is it possible to share you snippet, and can you provide some details like whether you used dot net core or dotnet framework and are you using rest api

Comment: Mine is .net core and asp.net core api. Here it is https://github.com/krish-gh/dotnetnode/blob/96235a768ed6f4addf96e8b45d447a96bdaf88c4/TestApi1/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs#L28

Comment: @krishg node version is latest but it is still taking npm older version like 1.1.37, I want to get latest npm version to run commands like npm run ng g or just ng g after installing angular/cli

Comment: Strange! for me, with the same code if I change the command to `npm -version`, it is also correct i.e. 6.14.4.

Comment: @krishg, in your code i tried npm -v & node -v , node version is correct but npm is 1.1.37 .so i tried WEBSITE_NPM_DEFAULT_VERSION=6.14.4, but no use. I am deploying my code from VSTS , framework dependent as deployment mode  to azure (no git pipeline) and haven't done any additional setting in azure. Have you done any addition setting in azure while deploying

Comment: It's pretty much same deployment mode for me. Just that I am publishing from VS itself (just for quick testing) and I have "remove additional files" on during publish.

Comment: @KavithaGowda Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the exact same issue: npm --version reports one version, but runtime is reporting 1.1.37.

Comment: No @Alex Eisenhart , I added complete node exe to azure and from that path I run npm command. Which is obviously bad approach